# Spring configuration nested object list not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config

I'm trying to setup spring boot to configure my app using this file:

```
templates.customTemplates[0].file=templates/loopwithpicturesandbasics.odt
templates.customTemplates[0].name=Simple look with pictures and multiple transforms
templates.customTemplates[0].transforms=mytransform
```

Here is the attached configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("templates")
public class TemplateConfiguration {

  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

  public static class TemplateItem {
    private String file;
    private String name;
    private String transforms;

    public TemplateItem() {
    }

    public String getFile() {
      return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
      this.file = file;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTransforms() {
      return transforms;
    }

    public void setTransforms(String transforms) {
      this.transforms = transforms;
    }
  }

  public TemplateConfiguration() {
  }

  public TemplateConfiguration(List<TemplateItem> customTemplates) {
    this.customTemplates = customTemplates;
  }

  private List<TemplateItem> customTemplates = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<TemplateItem> getCustomTemplates() {
    return customTemplates;
  }

  public void setCustomTemplates(List<TemplateItem> customTemplates) {
    this.customTemplates = customTemplates;
  }
}
```

Right now with this code the customTempaltes list is empty. If I remove the `static` from the inner class I get:

```
Binding to target [Bindable@6759f091 type = java.util.List<com.example.config.TemplateConfiguration$TemplateItem>, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: templates.customtemplates[0].file
    Value: templates/loopwithpicturesandbasics.odt
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:4:15
    Reason: The elements [templates.customtemplates[0].file,templates.customtemplates[0].name,templates.customtemplates[0].transforms] were left unbound.
    Property: templates.customtemplates[0].name
    Value: Simple look with pictures and multiple transforms
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:5:15
    Reason: The elements [templates.customtemplates[0].file,templates.customtemplates[0].name,templates.customtemplates[0].transforms] were left unbound.
    Property: templates.customtemplates[0].transforms
    Value: mytransforms
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:6:21
    Reason: The elements [templates.customtemplates[0].file,templates.customtemplates[0].name,templates.customtemplates[0].transforms] were left unbound.
```

(I tried both with properties and yml)

Comment: `TemplateItem` code ?

Comment: It's an inner class

Comment: Right didnt noticed, too much boilerplate code - offtopic: use Lombok.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding
`@EnableConfigurationProperties`. Maybe you didn't enable it anywhere.

Also, if that won't help declare your `TemplateItem` as package private class but not inner class like this (got the same in current project and it works):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("templates")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
    public TemplateConfiguration {
        ///bolierplate body
        private List<TemplateItem> items;
    }
    
    TemplateItem{
    /// another body
    }
```

Comment: Where should I add it too ? My main class ?

Comment: Add it to bootstrap class, or here, above your configuration. Would work in both cases

Comment: I tried adding the annotation, but it still doesn't work. The inner class is used in another package so it needs to be public

Comment: Then don't make it inner class as it is not "inner" but public. Make it public. But that is kind of offtopic as "should work" i think anyway.

Comment: Moved it into its own class and it's still not loading unfortunately

Comment: As I wrote, its kind of topic and should not influence that much, Check if `@Value{${templates.customTemplates[0].name}}`  resolves to anything meaningfull. If so, idk what is happening, if not - properties are not read.

Comment: It turns out the configuration is not being loaded. I tried adding a new string to my TemplateConfig and it's null

Comment: If it is in application.properties it should be loaded no matter what IMHO. Try to inject some of those properties with `@Value` or at least debug and see what is present in `Environment` as those properties will be as plain map. If they are not there - you are excluding it somewhere.